# XMPP Framework for Xcode8.1 with Swift 3

Tags: swift3, xmppframework, xcode8

I am trying implement XMPP chat functionality in Xcode8.1 with Swift 3.0, but unfortunately getting "Framework issues".

Currently I am using "https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios".

Any kind of work around solution or alternate supported framework will be a great help.

Thanks
Niladri